# Google Test Fixtures

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest, test-fixture

I'm trying to understand how the Google Test Fixtures work.

Say I have the following code:

```
class PhraseTest : public ::testing::Test
{
     protected:
     virtual void SetUp()
     {      
         phraseClass * myPhrase1 = new createPhrase("1234567890");
         phraseClass * myPhrase2 = new createPhrase("1234567890");  
     }

     virtual void TearDown()
    {
        delete *myPhrase1;
        delete *myPhrase2;  
     }
};



TEST_F(PhraseTest, OperatorTest)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(*myPhrase1 == *myPhrase2);

}
```

When I compile, why does it say `myPhrase1` and `myPhrase2` are undeclared in the `TEST_F`?

Comment: Another question: <br>
why you are using "delete *myPhrase1;"?<br>
I think the appropriate method to use delete is "delete myPhrase1;".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`myPhrase1` and `myPhrase2` are local to the setup method, not the test fixture.

What you wanted was:

```
class PhraseTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
     phraseClass * myPhrase1;
     phraseClass * myPhrase2;
     virtual void SetUp()
     {      
         myPhrase1 = new createPhrase("1234567890");
         myPhrase2 = new createPhrase("1234567890");  
     }

     virtual void TearDown()
     {
        delete myPhrase1;
        delete myPhrase2;  
     }
};

TEST_F(PhraseTest, OperatorTest)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(*myPhrase1 == *myPhrase2);

}
```

Comment: protected, says http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample3_unittest.cc

Comment: @BillyONeal Is the implied assumption that the code in SetUp() works? That is, you should use a normal TEST() (not TEST_F() ) for everything (here, the constructor) you are going to use in SetUp()?

Comment: @DavidDoria I assume SetUp is there for similarity with xunit.

Answer (score 3):

`myPhrase1` and `myPhrase2` are declared as local variables in the `SetUp` function.  You need to declare them as members of the class:

```
class PhraseTest : public ::testing::Test
{
  protected:

  virtual void SetUp()
  {      
    myPhrase1 = new createPhrase("1234567890");
    myPhrase2 = new createPhrase("1234567890");  
  }

  virtual void TearDown()
  {
    delete myPhrase1;
    delete myPhrase2;  
  }

  phraseClass* myPhrase1;
  phraseClass* myPhrase2;
};

TEST_F(PhraseTest, OperatorTest)
{
  ASSERT_TRUE(*myPhrase1 == *myPhrase2);
}
```